# Java, передача файла через Socket

Tags: java

Нужно передать файл  любого размера через сокет, желательно чтобы к этому возможно было прикрутить прогрессбар. (Интересуют именно файлы, сокет вполне работает, и к моменту передачи клиент и сервер готовы отдавать/принимать файл)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Какая разница что передавать, файлы или что-то другое?
2. Что значит клиент и сервер готовы? У них уже есть имя файла? Они уже знают размер передачи/принятия?

`client = new Socket("server", port);
bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("somefile.dat"));
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
byteArray = new byte[8192];
while ((in = bis.read(byteArray)) != -1){
    bos.write(byteArray,0,in);
}
bis.close();
bos.close();`

Comment: Имя файла есть, а вообще готовы потому что я передаю в приложении в основном текст, здесь сам факт передачи уже отловлен, нужно написать два метода, на приём и передачу(файлы могут передаваться в 2 стороны). Вообще с файлами ещё не сталкивался, поэтому идёт достаточно сложно.

Comment: Ну на передачу я вам кинул кусок кода. На прием этот же кусок в принципе будет, только Out на In замените ну и сокет там по другому получаться будет.. Отличий от текстовых сообщений нет, что там что тут - передача байт идет. Единственное отличие, что тут файлы имеют большие размеры очень и нужно передачу чанками делать (в примере 8 кб). На клиенте после приема чанка сразу же и пишите его в файл.

Comment: Всёравно не получается, файлы передаются, но не до конца, правда код не совсем ваш, посмотрите пожалуйста, в чём может быть ошибка? В методе recieveFile программа кажется не может выйти из цикла, а в sendFile отправляет почти мгновенно http://paste.org.ru/?r3o687

Comment: 1. i = (int) f.length() / 8192; - округляет в меньшую сторону

2. Из цикла выйти не можете, потому что у вас поток создан на 8192 * 100, а передаете вы туда очевидно меньшее количество байт.

Надеюсь помог.

Comment: + bis.read(byteArray) заставит текущий поток ожидать пока не наполнится этот 8192, поэтому надо делить на ровные доли( где-то в раене 8 кб(но чтобы сложив все эти доли вышел размер файла)) и  пересылать.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void sendFile(final File f) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Sending " + f.getName() + "...");
            out.println("@FILE_SEND"); 
            out.println(f.getName()); 
            try {
                byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f.getPath());
                long s;
                s = f.length();
                out.println(s);
                int sp = (int)(s / 1024);
                if (s % 1024 != 0) sp++;
                Main.mainFrame.createProgressPanel(f.getPath(), sp);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                Thread.sleep(500);
                while (s > 0) {
                    int i = fis.read(byteArray);
                    bos.write(byteArray, 0, i);
                    Main.mainFrame.progressInStream(1);
                    s-= i;
                }
                bos.flush();
                fis.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("File not found!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException");
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            new JOptionPane().showMessageDialog(null, f.getName() + " Sent");
            if (type == ClientServer.CLIENT_TYPE) Main.mainFrame.refreshFileList();
        }
    };
    new Thread(r).start();
}

private void recieveFile(String filename) {
    try {
        long s;
        s = Long.parseLong(in.readLine());

        System.out.println("File size: " + s);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
        new File("Recieved").mkdir();
        File f = new File("./Recieved/" + filename);
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        int sp = (int)(s / 1024);
        if (s % 1024 != 0) sp++;
        Main.mainFrame.createProgressPanel(filename, sp);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        while (s > 0) {
            int i = bis.read(byteArray);
            fos.write(byteArray, 0, i);
            Main.mainFrame.progressInStream(1);
            s-= i;
        }
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Recieve IO Error");
    }
    new JOptionPane().showMessageDialog(null, "Recieved " + filename);
}
```

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, старенько, но зато с прогрессом, а в чем жуть то?)

Comment: @And спустя 7 лет я перефразирую это в "неистовая жуть". 1. ввод-вывод происходит в непонятном потоке, из которого ещё и присходит работа с UI (такое ни в коем случае нельзя делать, только из AWT event loop можно обращаться к UI). 2. Логически сетевой код и UI код никогда не должны смешиваться. 3. тут нет никакой обработки ошибок ни в каких случаях. У всего этого есть в русском языке название: разгильдяйство.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, А `try catch` по вашему тут зачем? Почему нельзя делать так - кстати, это как так? И кто вам такое сказал, что нельзя на гуях строить сетевые приложения? Скажите - это тем людям, кто делает чаты и игры.

Comment: @And `try catch` тут просто так, потому что нельзя не написать потому что IOException и компания - это checked. И, конечно же, я никогда не говорил, что нельзя на гуях сетевые приложения делать. Я сказал, что нельзя из постороннего потока трогать UI, никогда нельзя. Так же как и наоборот: нельзя в UI потоке работать с сетью. И уж конечно никто из тех кто пишет сетевые приложения на гуях не станет всё в кучу валить как в этом примере. Это просто пример самого худшего, что только может быть. Логику приложения надо разделять. Да хоть про MVC что ли почитайте, в конце-то концов.