# Firebird. Декстоп приложение - передача изображения по сети

Tags: база-данных, firebird

Необходимо брать картинки через opendialog на машине клиенте и по нажатию на кнопку записывать файлик в папку на сервере а путь к файлу в базу Firebird. В отсутствии должного опыта не могу сообразить каким образом это возможно сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону смотреть

Возможно ли средствами сервера БД положить картинку не в базу а в файловую систему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: А как Вы эти файлы обратно извлекать будите? Если из файловой системы, то и записывать логичнее сразу файл. Ну а в базу просто название успешно созданого файла. Если извлекать из базы, то на фига в файл записывать?

Answer (score 1):

Технически, это реализуемо.

**Первый путь, "красивый"**

Взять C/С++/Pascal и написать плагин к серверу - UDF (user defined function), которой передавать в запросе BLOB с данными, а она будет писать его куда надо. Более того, кусок исходника даже [есть](http://www.delphigroups.info/3/11/232822.html).

Плюсы - из фронтенда все делается одним запросом к серверу БД, никаких костылей не нужно.

Минусы - обожемой, нужно знать страшные языки системного программирования.

**Второй путь, "админский"**

Совать данные во временную таблицу (в поля типа BLOB). После чего по расписанию на сервере гонять сценарий, который будет эту таблицу потрошить и перекладывать BOLOBы в файлы

Плюсы - как в первом способе, а также: ничего особенного писать не надо, встроенный инструмент isql умеет перекладывать blob в файл, нужно только все настроить.

Минусы - задержка перед появлением файлов

Comment: Не обязательно по расписанию. В Firebird же есть события. Даже какие-то компоненты для событий были прямо в делфи. Тригер, тригеря, вырабатывает событие. Программа не сервере слушает события и переписывает BOLOBы в файлы сразу же. Таким нехитрым способом минусуется минус задержки.

Answer (score 0):

Смотреть нужно в сторону создания текстового поля в таблице, где Вы будете хранить ссылку, и языка программирования на котором написан клиент (передача файлов по сети с его помощью). Потому,что сам FireBird вряд ли сможет выполнить подобные манипуляции с файлами.

Помещаете/копируете файл в нужную сетевую папку, а ссылку на него записываете в обычное текстовое поле в БД.

Как-то так...

**Для комментария:**

С помощью Java можно передавать файлы по сети с помощью `Socket`'ов. Данный механизм не требует открытия общего доступа к папкам. Серверное приложение (если у Вас "3х звенка") может получить файл по обычному сетевому протоколу и спокойно сохранить файл и ссылку на него. Аналогичный подход можно использовать и при выдаче сервером документов клиентскому приложению.

Подробно описывать, что такое `Socket`, к сожалению, формат ресурса не позволяет. Поэтому для наглядности приведу примеры [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/69136/) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12837/java-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-socket).

Comment: Я об этом думала, но не хочется открывать папку. (Язык Java). Может быть у на стороне сервера попробовать реализовать серверную часть специально для приема документов?

Comment: Непонятно при чём тут языки программирования?